# Where do usb wifi drivers go? 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I have a usb wifi dongle pluggedin and recognized, and have the linux driver, but the manufacturer's install disc failed, and I can't seem to get support, like where to put the now-unzipped driver.
 (OURLiNK Nano USB Wireless Adapter 600Mbps using realtek 802.11ac WLAN Adapter chipset rtl8192du as far as I can tell)

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dkms status` output:

`bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You need to add usb id to the driver.

Comment: How do I add the usb id to the driver, and why is this needed here and not for other drivers?

Comment: Which other drivers? Do any drivers work?

Comment: No other drivers work yet with the rtl8192DU chipset in the OURLiNK AC600. Realtek supplies  a driver with an install.sh script, which I am trying to use.

Comment: Oh, It is 8192DU. I made a dkms package for it. try to install it https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192du-dkms_0.1~trusty_all.deb You need to remove others first to be sure.

Comment: I changed the answer. I suggest removing `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `rtl8812au-dkms` before you install a new driver.

Answer (score 1):

If it is 8192DU device, try this driver.

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192du-dkms_0.1~trusty_all.deb

You need to download the file to your Home folder and run

```
sudo dpkg -i rtl8192du*.deb
```

I did not test it on kernel 4.4 yet. If it does not build I can patch it a bit. The drivers from the dongle rarely get installed on new kernels.

Comment: That appeared to work, but lshw still doesn't mention 'driver='...  under *-usb UNCLAIMED ... configuration: ...

Comment: Do not worry if it works.

Comment: You can check `usb-devices | awk '/a811/' RS=` to see the driver.

Comment: `usb-devices | awk '/a811/' RS=' returns ... Driver=(none)

Comment: Does the dongle work or not?

Comment: I don't see any likely looking wifi device names from my other devices wifi settings windows, so I think not. (I'm installing this on a 'distant'16.04 computer that I have ssh'ed to, through a terminal window on a 14.04 .)

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: I'll send you the dongle, if you give me your address - I've shifted to ordering a PCIe card from thinkpenguin. (I'd have PMed you, but can't yet.) Briancady413@yahoo.com

Comment: Thx, but I do not need the dongle. I do not make drivers. I pack them to a PPA. But all Realtek adapters do work with some effort.